# contradicting result about independence of events

Tags: probability

So Given a sequence of events $A_i , i\in \mathbb{N}$, we construct the sequence $B_n=\cap_{i=n}^{\infty}A_i$ and $C_n=\cup_{i=n}^{\infty}A_i$.

Here We have $B_n \subset C_n$. Let $B$ and $C$ be the limit of $B$ and $C$ respectively.

Now, I proved that $P(B\cap C)=P(B)*P(C)$ if $P(B_n \cap C_n)=P(B_n)P(C_n)$. 
However, it feels like the event $B$ and $C$ are not independent. 
Because as $B \subset C$, if $C$ occurred then for sure $B$ occurs. So then $B$ and $C$ are not independent? But why can I prove that they are?

Comment: you're not proving that they are. you are proving that they are under the assumption that $P(B_n \cap C_n) = P(B_n)P(C_n)$.

Comment: In the last two lines of your question, were $B$ and $C$ supposed to have subscripts? Did you mean do ask: "However, it feels like the events $B_n$ and $C_n$ are not independent. Because as $B_n\subset C_n$, if $C_n$ occurred then for sure $B_n$ occurs. So then $B_n$ and $C_n$ are not independent? But why can I prove that they are?"

Comment: oh good point! yes so the assumption that $B_n \subset C_n$ is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider events $D \subset E$.  Is it possible that they are independent?  Lets see...  if they are independent, then:

- $P(D) = P(D \cap E) = P(D)P(E)$
- $P(D) (1 - P(E)) = 0$
- $P(D) = 0$ or $P(E) = 1$

So in fact they can be independent in the "degenerate" cases.  That's why you could prove $B_n \subset C_n$ independent $\Rightarrow B \subset C$ independent.  You have made them degenerate.